# ¿Cómo le añado el connectionString de mi base de datos de Azure a mi proyecto?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure

Quería saber como cambiar el string de connection string de la base de datos.
La tengo en local y al desplegarla quiero poner la de la base de datos que hay en Azure.

El formato que uso es este:

```
Server=tcp:{server}.database.windows.net,1433;
Initial Catalog={nombre db};
Persist Security Info=False;
User ID={your_username};
Password={your_password};
MultipleActiveResultSets=False;
Encrypt=True;
TrustServerCertificate=False;
Connection Timeout=30;
```

Comment: que base de dato estas usando ? estas pensando poner esta en azure? vas a usar Sql Azure ?

Comment: el desarrollo lo estas realizando en .net core ?

Answer (score 0):

Normalmente, los datos que dependen del entorno en el que estés trabajando (desarrollo, producción...), se graban en archivos de configuración como web.config o app.settings.

La forma depende del tipo de proyecto que estés utilizando, por ejemplo en Asp.Net Core, para leer la configuración de una cadena de conexión, se utiliza un archivo appsettings, que se lee en el método `StartUp` de la aplicación:

```
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        IConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                                                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                                                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                                                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                                                .AddEnvironmentVariables();

    }
```

y para leer la configuración de una cadena de conexión:

```
IConfigurationRoot configuration = builder.Build();
string connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("Connection");
```

El archivo appsettings, para una base de datos SQL Server local para este caso sería:

```
{
   "ConnectionStrings": {
"Connection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=db;Trusted_Connection=True;"
}
```

Puedes ver más información en: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Answer (score 0):

Lo agregas por medio de la configuracion

[Azure Web App: Connection Strings](https://buildazure.com/2015/12/01/azure-web-app-connection-strings/)

En la `Web App` tienes una seccion de configuracion

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

despues usando la linea

```
 string value = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[key].ConnectionString;
```

podras tomar el valor en tu codigo